# C/C++ Windows+Linux ZIP Library for only unpacking?

Tags: c++, c, windows, linux, zip

Continuation of:
[Standalone Cross Platform (Windows/Linux)) File Compression for C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092690/standalone-cross-platform-windows-linux-file-compression-for-c-c)

After many attempts on ZLIB ZZLIB LIBZIP MINIZIP I always get many problems at the compilation stage. Many google searches turned out OS-specific libraries and I can't really find anything that fit my *'simple'* needs.

I reduced my needs for the library (Or wrapper?) to this:

- Works on both Windows and Linux ***OR*** 2 separate libraries; one which works on Windows and the other one on Linux, I can make 2 separate projects for Windows and Linux if it is really neccesary
- Unpack file from zip to specified directory
- Check if file exists in zip file
- C OR C++ OR Mixed (yeah, that doesn't matter)
- Preferably Very Simple to include into any project 
  (eg 5 c/cpp files and 1-3 header files? anyway not tons files, when I open all the libzip and zlib archives I have something like: "O my ..")

I've checked many stackoveflow threads too with the words "Windows Linux ZIP C C++" but all the results seem so have libraries which I OR don't know how to compile OR is too difficult to use OR it has too many 'needed stuff' for just simple zip extract and check if file exists.

I had put that project away for a later date and begun it now, and all those compilation errors came up (especially that VC++2010 doesn't have the C-99 inttypes.h)

Comment: How is running "make" too difficult?

Comment: first I try to compile on windows, then on linux... That's the way I always work as linux doesn't have so much problems.

Comment: `make` for Windows exists. Try MinGW.

Comment: Unfortunately for me I am FORCED to use Visual C++ (I preffer the 2010 edition). The reason is that the extensions I am making for the application, need to have linked a .def file to the DLL (else the application refuses them to load). This cannot be done in ANY another way than using the VC options. There is a community full of programmers who fail all the time at it. We all just need to keep using VC on Windows...

Comment: [Huh?](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSVC_and_MinGW_DLLs)

Comment: O_o, I think I'm going to try compile a random project and test it, time to wipe off the dust from my mingw installation (don't even remember when I installed it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had very good experience with [Zipstream](http://code.google.com/p/zipstream/) C++ library which gives you a nice OOP way of handling zip files.

If your project already uses some of the bigger libs like **Boost** , then you could try to use the *boost::iostreams* with the *gzip* filter, however the functionality is somehow limited.

Or if you happen to use **Poco** take a look at they're implementation [Poco::Zip](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Zip.html)

Comment: Hmm Zipstream needs zlib too? How about the MSVC C-99 inttypes.h which zlib requires?

Comment: now I never had any problem with building the zipstream library.